# Uploaded images don't immediately show on localhost

Tags: firefox, xampp

I am developing a site using XAMPP as a local server. I have a page on which users can upload images, and replace existing images withe new ones. When I test uploading images for the first time, everything works. But when I try to replace an existing image (call it 1.jpg), for some reason my browser refuses to show the newly uploaded picture, instead continuing to show the old one until by some fluke of either switching from localhost to 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.1.1, or restarting xampp, firefox, or the ubuntu os all-together, the image finally updates. If I look into the directory containing the images, 1.jpg is immediately replaced by the desired image, so I don't think it is a problem with my code. I tried automatically clearing the cache (I am using firefox), and that seemed to help a little, but only in that it now takes less time fiddling around before the browser updates the images. Could someone explain what is going on to me?

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly had images not displaying in FireFox only for localhost sites. Took me ages to find the problem...

Goto: Tools > Page Info
Select "Media" tab,
make sure the checkbox "block images from *localhost*" is unchecked. You'll need to be viewing the a localhost file when you view this dialog box to apply the change to localhost images.